# View Model requires information about control in xaml, MVVM way to do this?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

From what I understand of MVVM this is the wrong idea but I'd like to know if that is actually true and if so how to correctly achieve what I am trying to, or otherwise I'd like help on doing it.

I have a ConnectorViewModel which contains a class FullyCreatedConnectorInfo that stores the 'anchor point' of where a node should drop. To calculate this I require the following function:

```
public static Point GetPointForConnector(DesignerCanvas canvas, Connector source)
{
    Point p = source.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);
    p.X += source.Width / 2.0d;
    p.Y += source.Height / 2.0d;
    return p;
}
```

Where 'connector' is a UserControl of the connection point, DesignerCanvas is a Canvas which the connector resides in.

This function is called by the ConnectorViewModel to calculate a bezier curves start and end points which is binded to a property from the ConnectorViewModel.

I can make this work fine when the user is dragging points around as the events which end up getting called go through those controls so I have access to the connectors and canvas at the relevant points.

My issue is if I want to programatically create a ConnectorViewModel from say MainWindow.xaml.cs I require access to the connector control and the canvas. I can do something like this for the designer canvas:

```
<s:DesignerCanvas Loaded="DesignerCanvas_Loaded"
```

Then in the DesignerCanvas_Loaded function I can create a static reference to the designer canvas, since there is only one it sort of becomes a singleton. I'd really rather not do this however.

However for the Connector it's not so easy as it's defined using Data templates:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NodeViewModel}">
    <local2:Node/>
</DataTemplate>
```

So I'm not sure how I can find 'Node' from 'NodeViewModel'.

Even if I could figure it out I don't think this follows MVVM correctly since a ViewModel should not have to know what a Control has in it.

If it does abide by MVVM or doing it another way is too difficult and I have to do it this way I'd like help on how to do it?

The code is adapted from this sample: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/484616/MVVM-Diagram-Designer

Answer (score 0):

The post is lacking some sample code, but from what I get and in my opinion, you are already breaking MVVM by having your `GetPointForConnector()` in the ViewModel since you are referencing different types of UI Elements. Are the anchor points from `FullyCreatedConnectorInfo` taken from some sort of database? I would place these items on codebehind (i.e. View.cs) to properly follow MVVM. If they were from a database, you should probably bind the anchor points as objects (not UI elements) having simple `double`s to represent the coordinates and process them through a converter on your View. If they are not from some sort of database, then there's no reason they should be on the ViewModel, correct?

You should not need to find 'Node' from 'NodeViewModel'. This would be a sign of you breaking MVVM.

I think by moving these functions to the view and using converters, you might subsequently be able to achieve what you want.

**What I mean with using converters**:

For example, if you want to display the point on a textbox:

XAML:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:MultiConverter x:Key="multiconvert" ></local:MultiConverter>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <s:DesignerCanvas x:Name="DesignerCanvasName">
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiconvert}">
                <Binding ElementName="DesignerCanvasName" Path="."/>
                <Binding ElementName="ConnectorName" Path="."/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

Converter:

```
public class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DesignerCanvas cavas = values[0] as DesignerCanvas;
        Connector source= values[1] as Connector;
        Point p = source.TranslatePoint(new Point(0, 0), canvas);
        p.X += source.Width / 2.0d;
        // and so on

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is I can't calculate the anchoring point of the lines without access to the canvas and node control.

Comment: @soshiki Any reason why you can't bind to a converter / multiconverter?

Comment: The problem is that the paths are defined as a style in the DiagramDesigner project while the canvas is set in the MainWindow.xaml. In addition the actual connectors are defined in their own seperate user control (Node.xaml)

Comment: To explain more simply, the viewmodel controlling the connection lines is seperate to the viewmodel which contains the connection points.

Comment: @soshiki the architecture seems a little complicated...but you can make your ViewModels depend on each other and it won't break MVVM. :)